# Windows Server 2008 R2 versus Tortoise SVN

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, tortoisesvn

I installed tortoise SVN on a 2008R2 server. The install completed, I rebooted, but still no tortoise context menus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you perhaps install the **32-bit** version of Tortoise?

32-bit shell extensions do not work on 64-bit Windows operating systems (Windows Server 2008 R2 is 64-bit only), which is why the context menus do not appear.

[Download](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads) and install the **64-bit version** and reboot the server.

Comment: Hmm. I thought this was a 32-bit system. But I apparently misheard.

Comment: There is no 32-bit version of 2008 R2.  It's the first Microsoft OS only available as 64-bit.